# Computing the pull-back with exterior derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, pullback, exterior-derivative

I don't understand how to do the following question:
[image]
Property 5 is $\phi$*d$\omega$=d$\phi$ *$\omega$

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have 
$$
F : \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^6: (x, y, z) \mapsto (x, y, z, xyz, x^3 - y, 6x + 3z)
$$
And you have a $2$-form, $\omega$ on $\Bbb R^6$. You'd like to "compute" 
$$
\eta = F^{*}\omega,
$$
whatever that might mean, which should be a $2$-form on $\Bbb R^3$. That means that $\eta$ should be something that looks like
$$
\eta(p, q, r) = f(p,q,r) dp \wedge dq + g(p,q,r) dq \wedge dr  + h(p,q,r) dp \wedge dr
$$
i.e., you're supposed to write down the functions $f, g, h$. If you prefer a notation with lots of superscripts, etc., then you want
$$
\eta(x^1, x^2, x^3) = f(x^1, x^2, x^3)  dx^1 \wedge dx^2 + \ldots,
$$
but frankly, I think that's worse to read. To each their own.

I have no idea what the hint is getting at, but let's look at what 
$$
\eta(p,q,r) (e_1, e_2)
$$
should be. On the one hand, it should be

\begin{align}
\eta(p, q, r)(e_1, e_2)
&= f(p,q,r) dp \wedge dq (e_1, e_2)+ g(p,q,r) dq \wedge dr (e_1, e_2) + h(p,q,r) dp \wedge dr(e_1, e_2)\\
&= f(p,q,r) dp \wedge dq (e_1, e_2)+ g(p,q,r)\cdot 0  + h(p,q,r) \cdot 0\\
&= f(p,q,r) \cdot 1
\end{align}
Hold that thought.

On the other hand, it should also be

\begin{align}
\eta(p, q, r)(e_1, e_2) 
&= (F^* \omega)(p,q,r) (e_1, e_2)\\
&= \omega(F(p,q,r))(F_* (p,q,r) (e_1), F_* (p,q,r) (e_2))\\
&= \omega((p, q, r, pqr, p^3 - r, 6p + 3r))(F_* (p,q,r) (e_1), F_* (p,q,r) (e_2))\\
&= ( (p+r)~dw^3 \wedge dw^4 + 2 ~dw^6 \wedge dw^5 + q ~dw^1 \wedge dw^2)(F_* (p,q,r) (e_1), F_* (p,q,r) (e_2))\\
\end{align}
Now we need to compute $F_{*}$, which is just the derivative of $F$, so at $(p,q,r)$, it's multiplication by the matrix 
$$
\pmatrix{1 &  0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
qr & pr & pq \\
3p^2& -1 & 0 \\
6 & 0 & 3}
$$

Multiplying this by $e_1$ gives the first column; multiplying by $e_2$ gives the second column. So

\begin{align}
\eta(p, q, r)(e_1, e_2) 
&= ( (p+r)~dw^3 \wedge dw^4 + 2 ~dw^6 \wedge dw^5 + q ~dw^1 \wedge dw^2)(F_* (p,q,r) (e_1), F_* (p,q,r) (e_2))\\
&= ( (p+r)~dw^3 \wedge dw^4 + 2 ~dw^6 \wedge dw^5 + q ~dw^1 \wedge dw^2)(\pmatrix{1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
qr\\
3p^2 \\
6 }, \pmatrix{  0  \\
 1  \\
 0  \\
 pr  \\
 -1  \\
 0 })\\
\end{align}

So all we have to do is evaluate $dw^3 \wedge dw^4$ on that pair of vectors (we get $0$), $dw^6 \wedge dw^5$ (messier), and $dw^1 \wedge dw^2$. This last one gives $1 \cdot 1 - 0 \cdot 0 = 1$. So the middle one remains. Calling the two vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$, we need to compute
\begin{align}
s &= dw^6(v_1) dw^5(v_2) - dw^6(v2) dw^5(v_1) \\
&= 6 \cdot (-1) - 0 \cdot 3p^2 \\
&= -6.
\end{align}
So we end up with

\begin{align}
\eta(p, q, r)(e_1, e_2) 
&= ( (p+r)~dw^3 \wedge dw^4 + 2 ~dw^6 \wedge dw^5 + q ~dw^1 \wedge dw^2)(F_* (p,q,r) (e_1), F_* (p,q,r) (e_2))\\
&= ( (p+r)~dw^3 \wedge dw^4 + 2 ~dw^6 \wedge dw^5 + q ~dw^1 \wedge dw^2)(\pmatrix{1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
qr\\
3p^2 \\
6 }, \pmatrix{  0  \\
 1  \\
 0  \\
 pr  \\
 -1  \\
 0 })\\
&= ( (p+r)~\cdot 0  + 2 \cdot (-6) + q \cdot 1\\
&= -12 + q
\end{align}
from which we conclude that $f(p, q, r) = -12 + q$.

Now all you have to do is repeat that kind of computation to find the functions $g$ and $h$, and you're done.

Comment: Very clear, thank you!
So we don't use the property?

Comment: I suppose that it's possible that the $\omega$ in this problem is in fact $d\beta$ for some 1-form $\beta$; in that case, you could compute $F^* \omega$ as $F^{*} d \beta = (dF)^{*} \beta$, which might be easier. I wonder whether the difficulty might be that you should have been advised to use property 4, or property 6, of the cited lemma, and that property-numbers changed as the author(s) added some stuff, with the exercise not being updated. All that's just conjecture, of course.